# How to plot splom function?

Tags: r, lattice

i'm trying to recreate this graph

```
require(car)

scatterplotMatrix(~Week+Cases+Egg.Pr+Beef.Pr+Pork.Pr+Chicken.Pr+Cereal.Pr, reg.line = lm,
smooth = TRUE, spread = FALSE, span = 0.5, id.n = 0, diagonal = 'boxplot', data = Eggs)
```

using the lattice package,

i've been trying to make it work with this structure, but it just comes out wrong:

```
 splom(Eggs, panel = function(Week, Cases, Egg.Pr, Beef.Pr, Pork.Pr, Chicken.Pr, Cereal.Pr) {
   panel.xyplot(Week, Cases, Egg.Pr, Beef.Pr, Pork.Pr, Chicken.Pr, Cereal.Pr)
   panel.lmline(Week, Cases, Egg.Pr, Beef.Pr, Pork.Pr, Chicken.Pr, Cereal.Pr)
   panel.smooth(Week, Cases, Egg.Pr, Beef.Pr, Pork.Pr, Chicken.Pr, Cereal.Pr)
 }, spread = FALSE, span = 0.5, id.n = 0, diagonal = 'boxplot',
 data = Eggs)
```

please help me out, and overexplain as much as possible

Comment: Without reproducible data it is difficult to be specific. Your code seems to be based on old versions of `scatterplotMatrix` and `splom` so the first step is to get current versions of those functions.

Comment: specifically, where does the `Eggs` data set come from?  (Or can you set up an example using a built-in data set, e.g. `mtcars` or `USArrests` or ... ?)

Comment: this is the dataset https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BCA/versions/0.9-3/topics/Eggs, i downloaded it using a bca package

Comment: Please edit your code to include calls to `library()` and `data` to load needed packages & data sets, so people can just copy&run the code. Making helping as hassle-free as possible increases the probability of somebody helping

Comment: The dataset that you are using is from the BCA package, which was [removed from the CRAN repository last year](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BCA/index.html), so it would be best if you could provide this data using `dput(Eggs)` into your original question.

Answer (score 1):

With some guessing from context, and since you asked for overexplanation:

First, you need to refine your understanding of panel functions. They are supposed to be general purpose functions describing the plotting procedure, not specific to the data at hand. With that in mind, we can rewrite your first attempt as:

```r
myPanel <- function(x, y, ...) {
   panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
   panel.lmline(x, y, ...)
   panel.loess(x, y, ...)
}
```

Note that `panel.smooth` will not work, for reasons that are too complicated to get into (but basically, it's not grid-based, as lattice requires).

With this, you should be able to do

```r
Eggs <- Duncan[-1] # placeholder to make example reproducible
splom(Eggs, panel = myPanel)
```

This leaves the diagonal, for which you need another panel function. Here's one suggestion which can be fine-tuned as per your requirements:

```r
myDiagonal <- function(x, ...) { 
    diag.panel.splom(x, ...) # retain default and build on it
    ycenter <- quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
    panel.bwplot(x = x, y = rep(ycenter, length(x)), 
                 box.width = 0.1 * diff(range(x, finite = TRUE))),
                 ...)
}
```

Combining, you can now do

```r
splom(Eggs, panel = myPanel, diag.panel = myDiagonal)
```

The sprinkling of `...`-s are important, but I'm not going to go into why. For the rest, documentation of the corresponding functions should help you figure out how to fine tune.